# how to control which member value to be retrieved by variables

Tags: batch-file

```
set M1=R1
set M2=R2
set Obj.%M1%.%M2%=hi

set V1=% Obj.%M1%.%M2%%
echo %V1%
```

I hope this code print ‘hi’, but it failed. In my project, I need M1 and M2 to control which member of Obj to show its value, is it possible to implement this?

Comment: `CALL set "V1=%%Obj.%M1%.%M2%%%"`

Comment: `set V1=!Obj.%M1%.%M2%!` and add a `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` line at beginning.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: @Aacini thanks, the issue is resolved

Comment: If you think the linked answer helps to solve your problem, please upvote it **`;)`**

Comment: @Aacini I have upvote it